# Why my html table is getting out of my div?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a html table inside a div but the table is getting out of the div's width, here is what I am doing:

```
  <div style="width: 920px">
                            <table style="width: 100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

this is not working

Comment: can you please show the output here?

Comment: The problem is elsewhere (in your css probably). So we need more than that to help you.

Comment: there's no css it just this i can give a snapshot

Comment: I copied this code, and the div is exactly as wide as the table...

Comment: try <table width="100%">, not  style="width:100%" in table

Comment: @FlorianGl actually this should work but it's not working in here

Comment: ok this is weird but its solved ... i was dragging a html table control and placing it in my aspx page but now i am not dragging it, by writing the table code it coming nicely now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an empty layout so there is nothing to see. If you add height, you can see how it looks:

```
<div style="width: 920px;border:1px solid red;height:500px;">
                            <table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>​
```

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wEuRz/3/)

Comment: ok this is weird but its solved ... i was dragging a html table control and placing it in my aspx page but now i am not dragging it, by writing the table code it coming nicely now

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some attributes to the table to ensure there is no cell spacing:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Comment: Do you have CSS associated with this file? Tried it in JSFiddle with no problems.

Comment: ok this is weird but its solved ... i was dragging a html table control and placing it in my aspx page but now i am not dragging it, by writing the table code it coming nicely now